# Using an attribute from parted output

Tags: ansible

I need Ansible to install a server and I must partition for LVM. How can I use the attribute "size" from the second partition of "sda_info.partitions"?

```
hosts: node2
 become: yes
 become_method: sudo
 become_flags: -H -S
 tasks:
 - name: Some name
   parted:
     device: /dev/sda
     unit: s
   register: sda_info

OUTPUT

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [node2] => {
   "sda_info.partitions": [
       {
           "begin": 4096.0, 
           "end": 51202047.0, 
           "flags": [
               "boot"
           ], 
           "fstype": "ext4", 
           "name": "", 
           "num": 1, 
           "size": 51197952.0, 
           "unit": "s"
       }, 
       {
           "begin": 51202048.0, 
           "end": 52248575.0, 
           "flags": [], 
           "fstype": "linux-swap(v1)", 
           "name": "", 
           "num": 2, 
           "size": 1046528.0, 
           "unit": "s"
       }
   ]
}
```

Comment: This question is unclear. What is it exactly you're trying to achieve. And what is the desired output? Please update your post.

Answer (score 0):

*sda_info.partitions* is a list with 2 dictionaries. The 2nd dictionary can be referenced

```
sda_info.partitions[1]
```

and the attribute *size* can be assigned to a variable

```
- set_fact:
    size_2nd_part: "{{ sda_info.partitions[1].size }}"
```

Very probably the list will be sorted by the number of the partition. If not the variable above won't be the size of the 2nd partition. Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) to be sure

```
- set_fact:
    size_2nd_part: "{{ sda_info.partitions|json_query('[?num==`2`].size') }}"
```